# How to copy Http dirty data in Azure Data Factory

Tags: csv, http, copy, azure-data-factory

I need to automatically copy data (which is .csv) from a site (http pull) to an Azure SQL database where the data isn't ideal for me.
The columns are like Col_A, Col_B, Col_B
Then all the rows are like: OB, 00AB00, Worldpoint
Beside a couple of rows which are like: "OB, 00AB00, ""Worldpoint is better, than that"""
With Quote and Escape Character set to: "
It does copy the data but it moves the data where the rows start with " in the first column.
The fix I need is that it sets the data to the columns separated instead of in one column.
I've tried (I think) a lot of options for Quote and Escape Character, but haven't managed to get the right settings.
The most promising option is where I left the Quote and Escape Characters empty.
This showed the desired result but it is unable to copy the data to the Azure SQL database due to insufficient columns.
I've tried adding extra columns with no result.
What would be the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is where I fall back to my background in open source programming and don't try to do things natively in ADF.
I'd save the CSV somewhere (like azure blob), then use a Databricks notebook activity and use R or Python code to manipulate the file and clean up these quotes. A lot more flexibility that way because you can just work with the text as text, then write the file back out unquoted.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!  
I appreciate it a lot as I now know how to go at it with this problem.  
Hope you have a good day